# Django WebTest - I fill and save a form, data are updated in the new page but not in the database

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, caching, django-models

I have a test in which I create a Profile model with factory_boy and a biography with value 'Starting biography'.

Then I get the form from the page and I fill it the bio field with 'Test Updated Bio' and I see that the response has the updated value, but the database has not.

When I get the profile page after update I have the 'Test Updated Bio' in the HTML and 'Starting biography' in the biography field of the Profile model.

class ProfileFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

```
class Meta:
    model = 'profiles.Profile'

#user = SubFactory(UserFactory)
user = SubFactory('users.tests.factories.UserFactory', profile=None)
bio = 'Starting Bio'
```

The test function

```
def test_user_change_biography(self):
    test_bio = 'Test Updated Biography'

    form = self.app.get(
        reverse('profiles:update'),
        user=self.profile.user,
    ).form

    form['bio'] = test_bio

    tmp = form.submit().follow().follow()

    print('\n\n\n', tmp, '\n\n\n')
    print('\n\n\n', self.profile.__dict__, '\n\n\n')

    self.assertEqual(self.profile.bio, test_bio)
```

I thought that there could be some caching mechanism but I don't know. Some ideas ?

Comment: No, no ideas because you have not shown any code.

Comment: sorry, I post it right now

Comment: Updated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by refreshing the object from the database:

self.profile.refresh_from_db()

self.assertEqual(self.profile.bio, test_bio)